# Function to call onRightButtonPress in NavigatorIOS - React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, function, react-native, navigator

I'm using the onRightButton in a react-native NavigatorIOS.
I'd like to be able to call a function which resides into the component I'm pushing, but I can't get how to achieve that.
This is an example of code:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
  component: SingleResultView,
  title: "SomeTitle",
  rightButtonIcon: require('image!mapsmarker'),
  passProps: {
    userPosition: this.props.userPosition
  },
  onRightButtonPress: () => { SingleResultView.foo(); } // NOT WORKING!
});
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

The `ref` callback prop is your friend! https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute

```
  goToResults() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component: SingleResultView,
      title: "SomeTitle",
      rightButtonIcon: require('image!mapsmarker'),
      passProps: {
        userPosition: this.props.userPosition,
        ref: this.onResultsRef,
      },
      onRightButtonPress: () => { this._resultsView && this._resultsView.foo(); }
    });
  }

  onResultsRef(resultsViewRef) {
    this._resultsView = resultsViewRef;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SingleResultView` hasn't instantiated yet, so you have no access to its methods.

The following would work:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
  onRightButtonPress: SingleResultView.prototype.foo
});
```