# react-native update NavigatorIOS component's props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following code in which `HomeTab` contains a `NavigatorIOS`. I'm passing `HomeScreen` as the component for the navigator.

I have some events happening on a parent component that contains `HomeTab` and would like to pass them to `HomeScreen`. I am able to get the to `HomeTab`. How can I set the props or state for the component and preferably, I'd like to be able to call a function on it. Any clue?

```
class HomeTab extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {}
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <NavigatorIOS style={styles.container}
            initialRoute={{
              title: 'Home',
              component: HomeScreen,
              passProps: {}
            }}
        />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass them through that passProps object there.

I think you might be missing the other piece in your HomeScreen component.

```
var HomeScreen = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    },
```

Then in your root view you would do

```
class HomeTab extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {}
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <NavigatorIOS style={styles.container}
            initialRoute={{
              title: 'Home',
              component: HomeScreen,
              passProps: {text: 'Woot!'}
            }}
        />
    )
  }
}
```

N.B. that if you provide the isRequired that your code will slam to a halt if you don't provide it when you display/push HomeScreen.

Comment: I probably did not explain myself really well: I have a Geolocation service running in the parent and I need to call a function inside the component in order to update it. Passing the props once is not going to help. I need to be able to call a function on HomeScreen... =)

Comment: @Abdo then you need to have the called inside the new screen or from parent some other way and have it trickle down the change.

Comment: I ended up implementing a flux model for the app... It's too much for this specific case but I'm going to need it anyway =)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the navigator model breaks the React-y dataflow (as I've outlined in this answer, too: [What is the right way to save data from a list view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539877/what-is-the-right-way-to-save-data-from-a-list-view/30540614#30540614))

IMHO best way to achieve what you're trying to do is to have this Geolocation service provide a global subscription functionality that your `HomeScreen` component subscribes to. E.g. using the `Geolocation` module's API that ships with React Native:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {locationInfo: {...}};
    this._watchID = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      (locationInfo) => {this.setState({locationInfo});},
      (error) => {...},
      ...
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Geolocation.clearWatch(this._watchID);
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

If you're using some sort of custom location service in between the device APIs and your app, then I would model a similar API for that service. You could for instance use the `EventEmitter` library that ships with React Native.

Now, if you absolutely **must** get an instance of `HomeScreen` from `HomeTab`, then that's possible too, using the `ref` prop, as I've outlined in this answer: [Function to call onRightButtonPress in NavigatorIOS - React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441908/function-to-call-onrightbuttonpress-in-navigatorios-react-native/30605997#30605997)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer =) Doing the watch inside the component or using the `ref` prop don't sound like elegant solutions to me. I ended up implementing a flux model. The geolocation update would take place in the main application and the component needing the data would subscribe to that event. This was too much to achieve this little thing but the solution looks a little more elegant and reusable to me =)